# How to get siteroot path in Azure startup task instead of approot?

Tags: azure, command-line

I have an Azure web project that has configured startup task in ServiceDefinition.csdef.

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="Task.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
</Startup>
```

In Task.cmd I have code that needs web project path. Somethin like this:

```
InstallService.exe /webpath="%cd%"
```

but directory in startup task is different than real production path. (E:\approot vs. E:\siteroot\0).

Is there way how to get production path in my Task.cmd?

Thanks

Comment: The following will put the current path into variable %SCRIPTPATH%:

`SET SCRIPTPATH=%~p0`

Answer (score 1):

You will use a litle bit of PowerShell! You have to create one PowerShell script and modify your cmd.
Your Entire PowerShell file (startup.ps1) shall look something like:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$site = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Started'}
$siteRoot = $site.PhysicalPAth
$fileExe = "InstallService.exe"
& $fileExe  /webpath=$siteRoot
```

Note that this is not tested, so not guaranteed to work.
And your new startup.cmd shall look like this:

```
@echo off 
powershell -command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" 2>> err.out  
powershell .\startup.ps1 2>> err.out
```

Please take your time to go through [this good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2011/02/07/azure-startup-tasks-and-powershell-lessons-learned.aspx).

Comment: it works, but the startup task is usually executed before the IIS website is created, so we don't have a Started role yet

Comment: great that it works. Hmm, you are correct. I remember working with AppPool defaults instead of working with AppPool directly because of this issue. A possible solution is to make the startup task background type (default) and put some timer. Not a robust solution. What is the final solution that worked? I would like to include it in my answer